# How to move files from Parent directory to subdirectory in java?

Tags: java

I am able to copy the contents from one folder to Targetfolder including subfolders but also i need to copy only the files which are present in source directory to subdirectory.

Please find my below code:

```
       private static void copyFolder(File sourceFolder, File destinationFolder) throws IOException
   {
    //Check if sourceFolder is a directory or file
    //If sourceFolder is file; then copy the file directly to new location
    if (sourceFolder.isDirectory()) 
    {
        //Verify if destinationFolder is already present; If not then create it
        if (!destinationFolder.exists()) 
        {
            destinationFolder.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Directory created :: " + destinationFolder);
        }
         
        //Get all files from source directory
        String files[] = sourceFolder.list();
         
        //Iterate over all files and copy them to destinationFolder one by one
        for (String file : files) 
        {
            File srcFile = new File(sourceFolder, file);
            File destFile = new File(destinationFolder, file);
             
            //Recursive function call
            copyFolder(srcFile, destFile);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Copy the file content from one place to another 
        Files.copy(sourceFolder.toPath(), destinationFolder.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        System.out.println("File copied :: " + destinationFolder);
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a new parameter to copyFolder. If set to false only the files are copied, not the folder:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Source directory which you want to copy to new location
    File sourceFolder = new File("/workspace/files/");

    // Target directory where files should be copied
    File destinationFolder = new File("/Workspace/Out/");

    // Call Copy function
    copyFolder(sourceFolder, destinationFolder, false);
}

/**
 * This function recursively copy all the sub folder and files from sourceFolder
 * to destinationFolder
 */
private static void copyFolder(File sourceFolder, File destinationFolder, boolean subFolders) throws IOException {
    // Check if sourceFolder is a directory or file
    // If sourceFolder is file; then copy the file directly to new location
    if (sourceFolder.isDirectory()) {
        // Verify if destinationFolder is already present; If not then create it
        if (!destinationFolder.exists()) {
            destinationFolder.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Directory created :: " + destinationFolder);
        }

        // Get all files from source directory
        String files[] = sourceFolder.list();

        // Iterate over all files and copy them to destinationFolder one by one
        for (String file : files) {
            File srcFile = new File(sourceFolder, file);
            File destFile = new File(destinationFolder, file);

            // Recursive function call
            if (subFolders) {
                copyFolder(srcFile, destFile, subFolders);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Copy the file content from one place to another
        Files.copy(sourceFolder.toPath(), destinationFolder.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        System.out.println("File copied :: " + destinationFolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: user1855085....Please it is not working as an example i explained in the question.Please suggest me on the way I need.I need to copy the folders and files but the files with same name has to replaced with the subfolder files

Comment: Can we do copy for the destination folder after copying everything to destination.Need to copy the basedir files to subdir folder from the destination side.Please help me this as I need to submit today and it is urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Files.walk` to create a stream of Path instances, filter the files and copy them to the destination.

```
try(Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.walk(sourceFolder)) {
    pathStream
           .filter(path -> path.toFile().isFile())
           .forEach(path -> {
                Path destinationFile = Paths.get(destinationFolder.toPath().toString(),
                        path.getFileName().toString());
                copyFile(path, destinationFile);
            });
}

private static void copyFile(Path src, Path dst) {
    try {
        Files.copy(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting exact what I need after using your code.Please suggest me to copy files and folders from parent to subdirectory.Please help me out as I need to submit today

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected and the actual behaviour?

Comment: Expecting to copy the files from basedir to subdir. Your code is copying files only to basedir from subfolder.

Comment: If you assign destinationFolder as the subdir, it would copy it inside it

Comment: Destination folder is not a subdir inside destinationFolder there are two subdirectories need to copy files to those subdirectories.